# multiple images upload using FormData and separate fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, upload

i want to start upload images to the server before submit the form
can't nest forms so i use formdata()

the form contain title and 5 images with captions , i want to start upload once i choose the image without click upload , and without submit the main form ,  prevent submiting the form until images uploaded

this a part of the code 
it work well with the first input only

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;



    $("#howaddButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>25){
    alert("error");
    return false;
    }



    $('#file' counter +).change(function(){
    var file_data = $('#file' counter +).prop('files')[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file' counter +, file_data);
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  form_data,
        contentType: true,
        cache: false,
        processData:true,



        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

        }

    });
    });



    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
    .attr("id", 'howTextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html(

    '<span id="content' + counter + '"><div class="btn btn-primary btn-file alert">'+

        '<div id="response">'+'</div>'+

    '<input type="file'+ counter +'" name="file'+ counter +'" id="file'+ counter +'">'+



    '</div></span>');

});

});
```

..

```
<div id="howTextBoxesGroup">
<div id="howTextBoxDiv1">

<li><a>
<input class="form-control input-md" placeholder="" required="required" type="textbox" name="how[0]" >
</a></li>



<span id="content">
    <div class="btn btn-primary btn-file alert"> 

    <div id="response"></div>

<input type="file" name="file" id="file">


</div>
</span>


</div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-success"   name="plus" id="howaddButton" type="button">+</button>
<button  class="btn btn-primary" name="minus" id="howremoveButton" type="button">-</button>
```

i think here is the problem

```
        '<div id="response">'+'</div>'+

        '<input type="file" name="file" id="file">'+
```

and how to alert if file size large than X Or its format not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your input file as multiple to be able to pick many files.

Also you need to iterate over files when you have chosen the files, and listen on change event of the input to be able to read that files.

I made a single example, I hope you find it helpful.

**EDIT**

Here you have the working code as you expected, now you can create input dynamically.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     // let's encapsulate the code to prevent its exposeness in the window scope that is accessible from console developer tools
      // soe let's make a autoexec function, and let's declare all our login inside
      
      // the ($) code will get the object injected at the bottom of the function
     (function($){
       // our counter images uploaded
       var imagesUploaded = [];
        // our limit to be reached
        var limitToBeReachedToEnableTheForm = 0;
        
        // reference to our btnSubmit
       var btnSubmit = $("#myBtnSender");
        // reference to our form
        var form = $("#MyForm");
        // let's save reference for each input file
        var picker = $(".file-picker");
        var blockWrapper = $(".wrap-block");
        var addBlockBtn = $("#add-picker-block");
        var blockId = "block-id-";
        
        // let's listen for picker (change) event for each input file
        function onHandleFile(event) {
         // get the file
          var file = event.target.files;
          // get the only file inside of the collection files
          file = file[0];
          var fileId = $(this).attr("id");
          
          // let's make sure file is actually an image, so we need to define what format of images we will allow
          var allowImagesTypes = ["image/jpg","image/gif", "image/png", "image/jpeg"];
         var imageType = file.type;
         
         // if the current image type is not supported, just abort the process and notify to user
         if (allowImagesTypes.indexOf(imageType) === -1) {
           var messageAllowedTypes = allowImagesTypes.join(", ");
           alert("Error, we only support these types of images : " + messageAllowedTypes);
            return false;
         }
         
         // if the current type image is allowed so let's get the title, caption and let's upload the image
         var currentPicker = $(this);
         var parentPickerBlock = currentPicker.parent(".block-image-picker");
         var title = parentPickerBlock.find('.image-title');
         title = title.length > 0 ? $.trim(title.val()) : "";
         var caption = parentPickerBlock.find('.image-caption');
         caption = caption.length > 0 ? $.trim(caption.val()) : "";
         
         uploadImage(title, caption, file, parentPickerBlock, fileId);
        };

        form.submit(function(){
          // if imagesUploaded is less than limitToBeReachedToEnableTheForm, so there are images to be upload and not allow the submittion of the form
          if (imagesUploaded.length < limitToBeReachedToEnableTheForm) {
           return false;
          }
          alert("Your form will send :D");
          return true;
        });
        
        addBlockBtn.on("click", addNewBlock);
        
      function checkTotalImagesUploaded(fileId) {
         if (fileId) {
           imagesUploaded.push(fileId);
          }
          
          // if the 5 images were uploaded so enabled the submit button
          checkUploadsToEnableSubmitButton();
        }
        
        function checkUploadsToEnableSubmitButton() {
         if (imagesUploaded.length === limitToBeReachedToEnableTheForm) {
           btnSubmit.removeAttr("disabled");
          } else {
           btnSubmit.attr("disabled", "disabled");
          }
        }
        
    function removeImageUploadedCounterIfExists(fileId) {
          var index = imagesUploaded.indexOf(fileId)
          if (index > -1) {
             imagesUploaded.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
        
        function addNewBlock() {
         // Create the block inputs elements
         var blockImagePicker = $("<div class='block-image-picker'>");
          var inputTitle = $("<input type='text' name='imageTitle[]' class='image-title' placeholder='Your image title' />");
          var inputFile = $("<input type='file' name='images[]' class='file-picker' />");
          // generate timestamp of creation
          var fileId = new Date() * 1;
          inputFile.attr("id", fileId);
          // put into the blockImagePicker
          blockImagePicker.append(inputTitle);
          blockImagePicker.append(inputFile);
          // add to block wrapper
          blockWrapper.append(blockImagePicker);
          // increment our limit counter
          limitToBeReachedToEnableTheForm++;
          // add data-id attribute
     blockImagePicker.attr("id", blockId + limitToBeReachedToEnableTheForm);
          if (limitToBeReachedToEnableTheForm > 1) {
      var removeBtn = $("<button>Remove</button>");
           blockImagePicker.append(removeBtn);
            removeBtn.data("container-id", blockId + limitToBeReachedToEnableTheForm);
      removeBtn.on("click", onRemoveBlockPicker);
          }
          // add event listener to file picker
          inputFile.on("change", onHandleFile);
          checkUploadsToEnableSubmitButton();
        }
        
    function onRemoveBlockPicker(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         // get input file to remove eventListener
          var filePickerReference = $(this).prev();
          var fileId = filePickerReference.attr("id");
          // remove event listener
          filePickerReference.off("change");
          // get block id for current block
          var containerId = $(this).data("container-id");
          var containerBlock = $("#"+containerId);
          containerBlock.remove();
          limitToBeReachedToEnableTheForm--;
          removeImageUploadedCounterIfExists(fileId);
          checkUploadsToEnableSubmitButton();
        }
        
        function uploadImage(title, caption, file, parent, fileId) {
          var formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("title", title);
          formData.append("caption", caption);
          formData.append("image", file);
          var loader = $("<div>");

          $.ajax({
            url: 'http://my-url-endpoint-rest',
            data: formData,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
             //beforeSend the image to upload, let's show the user what is happening
              loader.text("Uploading " + file.name + " ...");
              parent.append(loader);
            },
            success: function(response) {
              // if the image was uploaded so increment our counter imagesUploaded
              checkTotalImagesUploaded(fileId);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
             // show some error if something was wrong
              console.log("error", errorMessage); // Optional
              alert("Error uploading the image " + file.name);
            },
            complete: function() {
         // remove the loader, not matter if the response was wrong or good
              loader.remove();
            }
          });
        }
        
        // create our first block when page is loaded
        addNewBlock();
      })($);
      // the ($) code above will inject the jQuery object into the closure
    });
```

```css
.block-image-picker {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.block-image-picker input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="MyForm">
      <div class="file-pickers-wrapper">
        <div class="wrap-block">
        </div>
        
        <div class="controls">
          <button id="add-picker-block">
          add new field
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" id="myBtnSender" disabled="disabled">
        Send data
      </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: thanks a lot ,but i want the file input upload only one image , like this <input type="file" id="file1">  <input type="file" id="file2">   <input type="file" id="file3">

Comment: the form contain title and 5 images with captions , i want to start upload once i choose the image without click upload , and without submit the main form , and can't submit the form until images uploaded

Comment: @afm7 so you need to upload the 5 images, each image has a title and a caption field right? the title and caption are required or can be empty ?, so you only need that once you have chosen the image, when you have chosen the 5 images ? or in the way that you choose each image it should upload and when you have uploaded 5 images, so there you can submit the main form, is that ?

Comment: @afm7 I just edit my answer to add the working code that you need, I hope it can help you a lot :D

Comment: thanx it help me ,what if i want it to be unlimited not just 5

Comment: @afm7 you should make a function to add or remove the block image-picker element, obviously attach event listener for add button and remove button., and variable limitToBEReached should be handle by the adding or removing of the function

Comment: sorry , but when i use add remove buttons upload not working   http://jsfiddle.net/aaki/hMJEy/1/

Comment: Ok let me check it out

Comment: @afm7 ok I saw your code, but that code is completely different of the first approach I made, because I don't see the file picker, and the validations that I made in the example, can you explain in a clear way what you really need ?

Comment: i need a code like yours but only one file input and text input , i can add more by (add/remove) buttons

Comment: mmmm got it, ok just the only thing you need to do, is add block file picker element, and increment the counter , I will make some changes in the example code, and then I will edit the answer to help you ;)

Comment: i tried to make add/remove buttons but upload file do nothing , i use clone() and the last code i posted

Comment: thanks for the help , btw onclick (add) it should add one  file input and one text input , and remove as well

Comment: @afm7 I just edit my post again to help you with what you need, hope it help you.